# Set namespace from variable in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

When trying to set the `XMLNS` attribute dynamically from the data sent in it displays this error message when opening the XML file:

> error on line 1 at column 76: xmlns: '{Table/namespace}' is not a
>   valid URI

When printing out the value normally to an element, as in the node `namespace` below, I can see that the value is correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
        <MyRoot xmlns="{Table/namespace}" >
            <namespace>
                <xsl:value-of select="{Table/namespace}" />
            </namespace>
        </MyRoot>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How does one set the `XMLNS` attribute dynamically from the sent in data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly use [`xsl:element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256047(v=vs.110).aspx) to make use of its `namespace` attribute which does set the `xmlns` attribute in the output XML:

```
<xsl:element name="MyRoot" namespace="{Table/namespace}">
    <namespace>
        <xsl:value-of select="Table/namespace" />
    </namespace>
</xsl:element>
```